# PowerBI Odata date difference duration calculation from today

Tags: datetime, powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a PowerBI report connecting to azure devops. I am trying to pull date difference in days between utc today(may be devops timezone) and work item created. I tried the below odata query but it fails loading data. Any suggestion on where I am doing wrong here?

```
let

   Source = OData.Feed("https://abc.dev.azure.com/xyz/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?"
    &"$filter=(Project/ProjectName eq 'pqr' or Project/ProjectName eq 'ccd')"

   &"&$select=WorkItemId,CreatedDate,@(Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),-CreatedDate), "yyyy-MM-dd"))"
   null, [Implementation="2.0", OmitValues=ODataOmitValues.Nulls, ODataVersion=4])
in
    Source
```

Comment: You can't use M expressions directly in an OData query.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trails, I am able to figure out the solution. Posting the solution  to make sure someone will come across similar scenario.

I created a new column and added the below logic for that column.

```
EntendedDays = DATEDIFF(UTCNOW(), MyDataSetName[DateColumnName],DAY)
```